# Confusion as acceleration seen from different angles disagree with each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

[image]

Heres the question:

> Find the tension in the chord when the balls height above the lowest position is $\frac{1}{2}L$. Answer should be in terms of $g$ and $m$.

The solutions manual decided to orient an axis so that the $y$ axis is parallel to the chord in this moment and use newtons laws. Hence they had $$\mathbf{F}_{net-y} = m\mathbf{a}_c$$ $$\mathbf{F}_T-mg\sin 30^\circ =\frac{mv^2}{L}$$ Now this makes sense but I noticed that one *could* orient the axis so that the y axis is parallel to gravity on the mass. In other words we would have that $$\mathbf{F}_{net-x} = m \mathbf{a}_{c-x} \implies \mathbf{F}_T\cos 30^\circ = m \mathbf{a}_{c} \cos 30^\circ \implies \mathbf{F}_T= m \mathbf{a}_{c}$$ But then we would have that $$\mathbf{F}_{net-y} = m\mathbf{a}_{c-y} \implies \mathbf{F}_T\sin 30^\circ -mg = m \mathbf{a}_c \sin 30^\circ \implies mg=0$$ which is ridiculous. I am truly lost as to why this isn't working. To my understanding, the orientation of the axis is relative and the same answer should be had no matter the orientation. Any clarity would be much appreciated.

Comment: This could use more details - what is $T$, what is $a_c$, where the $30$ degrees is coming from, etc. Maybe add on the diagram where $y$ is pointing in both cases, as well (it is highly unusual to have a y-axis that isn't in the vertical direction, but you seem to imply the solutions manual does exactly that).

Comment: @Allure I see $y$ directions that are not in the vertical direction in almost ever physics text I see. e.g. when a block is on a ramp it is very useful to tilt the $y$ axis so that it is perpendicular to the surface of the ramp. In this example, it is useful to tilt the $y$ axis so that it is parallel to the pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ball's acceleration isn't totally centripetal. It is speeding up. This means that the acceleration vector cannot point at the axis of rotation, but below it (in the -y direction). What you derived is the following: if the acceleration of the ball points towards the pivot, then there is no gravity. When you set acceleration to $(a_C \cos\theta, a_C \sin\theta),$ the acceleration points towards the pivot. The second equation in the book's solution gives the acceleration tangent to the circle.

Comment: You mean that the book is talking about acceleration in the radial direction. Small typo? Anyway, it is clear that because the OP made a mistake by ignoring that there is tangential acceleration and not just centripetal acceleration, the resulting equations are inconsistent and thus generated an absurdity.

Comment: I thank you for your help. You are right for some reason in my head I was thinking if there is centripetal acceleration then there is *only* centripetal acceleration which is silly.